# Heat equation on a graph Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, partial-differential-equations, graph-laplacian

I would like to start with considering the time-dependent heat equation on a connected graph.
To start, I will need to model it respect to time discretization. I mean I have to write something like:
    $$A T^{k+1} = B T^k + Cf^k$$
where the initial time is given and the time step is assumed to be fixed. First, I have to determine the matrix A, B, and C and write down in what form they will be.

Would you please let me know if you know some references or have some comments on this topic?

Comment: What is 'heat equation on graph'? Could you use the graph's Laplacian?

Comment: @daw:Yes, it is exactly graph Laplacian and then I use the Laplacian matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Try this document

[PDE Approaches to Graph Analysis (Justin Solomon, Stanford)](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.stanford.edu%2F~justso1%2Fassets%2Fqual.pdf&ei=ZkdWVeLFAeiz7gbmiYDwDw&usg=AFQjCNEEoIV6ktX4DZAj7WgbGmQoaVcVBg&bvm=bv.93564037,d.ZGU)